# Why does MySQL ship with two identical test runners (mysql-test-run and mysql-test-run.pl)?

Tags: mysql, testing

I'm trying to figure out why there are two, nothing in their documentation explains the reason.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, especially in open-source software, when you encounter two identical executables with different names it's because one version is there for backward-compatibility reasons. Although, usually this is handled by either a symbolic or hard link instead of a full extra copy of the file.